# How describe Post body as object with deepObject encoding?

Tags: swagger, openapi

API require to pass POST body as form object. For example how Postman makes requests:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://api.mysite.local/v1/site/login \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F 'LoginForm[login]=username' \
  -F 'LoginForm[password]=password'
```

How can I describe this with OpenAPI 3.0? Due to large amount of reusable forms and data objects, I desided to place them in `/components/schemas` and reuse in request description with $ref:

```
paths:
  /site/login:
    description: "Authorization"
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            type: object
            properties: 
              LoginForm:
                $ref: "components/schemas/LoginForm"
            encoding: 
              LoginForm:
                style: deepObject
                explode: true
components:
  schemas:
    LoginForm:
      type: object
      properties:
        login:
          type: string
        password:
          type: string
      required:
        - login
        - password
```

Unfortunately that did not worked, when I execute `widdershins --expandBody 'api.yml' -o 'api.md'`, body parameters section is empty. Whad I do wrong?

Comment: Your Postman example uses `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` and your OpenAPI spec specifies `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Which exactly content type are you supposed to use? They are [encoded differently](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST#Example).

Comment: @Helen, I think that's not important because backend can work with both requests. My problem is to define request body as Object[property]=value in docs. Now it is emty

Comment: I know this is an old question but did you ever manage to config the swagger to allow deepObject in a POST request?